# Handling user login and keeping the user logged in?

Tags: android, android-studio, authentication, retrofit, retrofit2

My website has a login feature that lets the user enter their email and password to login to their own account. I now need to have this same functionality brought over to my app.

I have a view already set up with an email and password input field. What I'm confused with is the logic behind logging the user in.

I'm using Retrofit to make calls to my API.

I found this tutorial online, but I'm not sure if this will help me do what I need:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/android-basic-authentication-with-retrofit

I also found this tutorial (for token authentication), so now I'm doubly confused as to whether or not either of these will help me or if they're for something else:

https://futurestud.io/tutorials/retrofit-token-authentication-on-android

**So my question is, using Retrofit, how do I authenticate a user login, and upon successful authentication, how can I make later calls to my API using the user ID (from the database)?**

Comment: Easiest way to do this is to store user input data in SharedPreferences. At Activity create you need to check if there is stored user data to continue to main activity, if there is nothing, ask user to type login data...

Comment: Can SharedPreferences not be maliciously edited? For example, if someone wanted to change their user ID to access some other user's data in a future API call, is it possible for them to edit that information?

Comment: @MilosLulic That is HORRIBLE advice.  NEVER EVER store authentication data on the client device.  This makes your account vulnerable to anyone who hacks your phone.

Comment: @GabeSechan i agree with you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use token based authentication.  When you login, the server sends you a random token and stores it in its db.  You save that random token.  In all future calls, you pass up that random token.  The server checks the token before processing each call.  Remember to use HTTPS so that your data is encrypted in transit.

Why is this better than storing username and password?  First, you can easily revoke the token server side.  Secondly, if the user reuses his password on multiple sites then he hasn't just compromised one account, he's compromised all of them.  With a token he has at worst compromised this account.

Comment: Ok, so this is for AFTER the user is authenticated, correct? The DB would store a token associated with that user ID, and then each API call from the app would include that token and would check for a match, yes? What about the authentication itself? Would I just send the user data from the email and password input fields to an API endpoint like `/user/login/{email}/{password}`? Should I encrypt the password before sending it (even though it will be through HTTPS)?

Comment: I'd use POST rather than GET, so you'd just go to user/login and POST the parameters (the reason for POST over GET, other than philosophy, is that if you use GET then their password would be all over the logs).  No need to encrypt the password before sending, HTTPS will encrypt it.  However you should not save the user's password in your DB-  you should store the salted hash of the password.